# An exercise in Gathmann's lecture notes about Projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Exercise 3.5.1 in Gathmann's lecture notes:

> Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two disjoint lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and let $P\in \mathbb{P}^3 \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2)$ be a
>   point. Show that there is a unique line L meeting $L_1$, $L_2$, and $P$ (i. e. such that $P \in L$ and $L \cap L_i \neq \emptyset$ for $i=1,2$.

And is it true that a line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is given by a system of two homegeneous linear equations?

Comment: Can you show your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: @egreg I can show that a line is given by two homogeneous linear equations(I need two points to give the eight coefficients of the system). There are infinitely many lines through P, but I don't know how to find another point to fix the line I wanted. Thanks!